# Windows Sandbox run logincommand as WDAGUtilityAccount

Tags: windows, sandbox, windows-sandbox

Trying to automate some installs, but seems as though the scripts within the directive don't get ran as WDAGUtilityAccount.

If I try to use the runas command it requires a password. Would there be a possibility to specify which account I'd like things ran as from the directive?

Current wsb config looks like the following:

```
<Configuration>
  <MappedFolders>
    <MappedFolder>
      <HostFolder>C:\Scripts</HostFolder>
      <SandboxFolder>C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Downloads\scripts</SandboxFolder>
      <ReadOnly>true</ReadOnly>
    </MappedFolder>
  </MappedFolders>
  <LogonCommand>
    <Command>C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Downloads\scripts\setup.cmd</Command>
  </LogonCommand>
</Configuration>
```

Where setup.cmd looks something like:

```
REM get python
curl -L "https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.11.2/python-3.11.2-amd64.exe" --output C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Downloads\python-3.11.2-amd64.exe

REM install python
C:\Users\WDAGUtilityAccount\Downloads\python-3.11.2-amd64.exe /quiet  AppendPath=1  InstallAllUsers=1
```

Python get's installed, but the path isn't configured properly. I know this would be because of the user which is running the commands at logon but how would I select which user?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added additional information.